# Switch to Window not working for chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: On the click of an icon button, a new window will be opened.

I am using the below code:

```
String strNewWindowTitle = "New Window";    
Set<String> winHandles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = winHandles.iterator();
String strcurrentWinHandle = null;

    int counter = 0;

    while (it.hasNext()) 
    {
        strcurrentWinHandle = it.next();
        counter++;
        webDriver.switchTo().window(strcurrentWinHandle);
        while (!webDriver.getTitle().equals(strNewWindowTitle)) 
        {
            strcurrentWinHandle = it.next();
            counter++;
            webDriver.switchTo().window(strcurrentWinHandle);
        }
    }
```

I am doing this on `Chrome v60.0.3112` and on clicking the button the window is not staying on the screen. The code works fine for Firefox.

Any suggestions as to why is this behaving in this way?

Comment: ArrayList<String> tabHandles = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
for(String handles:tabHandles){
driver.switchTo().window(handles);

}

Comment: Seeing your code I would suggest you to extract the code within your while blocks to a separate method. Would greatly improve readability.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep the logic is working for firefox, but not on chrome, Can you help me in that respect.

Comment: What do you mean by window is not staying on the screen? does it open and close or it doesn't open at all? Can you check developer console and see any errors in there

Comment: @TarunLalwani the window opens and closes quickly. I guess I wont be able to use the dev console while selenium execution.

Comment: @Alapan, why can't you use dev console? It works even with selenium?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly happens when you say `window is not staying on the screen`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this code instead after the click is performed. There is no need for a while loop for just two windows. In fact while wouldn't be necessary even if there are more than two windows.

```js
Set <String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator <String> it = ids.iterator();
String currentWindow = it.next();
String newlyOpenedWindow = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(newlyOpenedWindow);
//do your operations on the new window here
   
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);// if you want to get back to the previous window
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer. But my problem solved when I ramped down my browser to v 51. It seems that there was a problem in which the web app was created. The above code is working fine with Chrome 51.